# How to remove .html suffix?

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect, html, htaccess, suffix

**I have a running store with around 600 products and wanted to remove the HTML suffix from my URLs.**

I removed the HTML in the config and reindexed. All HTML pages are being redirected to the non-HTML variants.

I have read online people are putting  the 301 redirects manually in their .htaccess

> e.g. `RewriteRule ^index.php/?(.*).html$ /$1 [R=301,L]`

But is this really necessary when I don't get 404s?

Is manual .htaccess 301 redirect necessary?

Any insight appreciated

**Thanks**

Comment: Is the current redirect status code 302 or 301

Comment: Hello, I have "Search Engine Optimizations" -> "Create Permanent Redirect for URLs if URL Key Changed" set to yes and magento seems to automaticaly add a 301 redirect for all .html pages. But there is nothing in my .htaccess Thanks

Comment: it's completely unnecessary to redundantly do this in .htaccess then

Comment: Thanks, don't have much experience with Magento, yet.

Answer (score 0):

In theory when you updated the config magento should have created the redirects in the url rewrite db table. Therefore updating htacess is unnecessary.